# Creating two blogs on same website (Jekyll GitHub) without altering layout/formatting

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, blogs, posts

I have recently tried creating a website using the Jekyll GitHub template [here](https://alembic.darn.es). One major alteration I hope to make to this template is to have two "blogs" in the format provided in the Blog tab of that template specifically shown [here](https://alembic.darn.es/blog/).

I (sort of) successfully created two blogs in my website and named the associated tabs ([Media](https://testmdrs.github.io/media/)) and ([Blog](https://testmdrs.github.io/blog/)). I achieved this by reorganizing the file structure to have a "[media](https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/tree/master/media)" folder and a "[blog](https://github.com/testMDRS/testMDRS.github.io/tree/master/blog)" folder separately that each contain a `_posts` folder and `index.html` file. Now, when I add `.md` files in the `_posts` folder, these posts seem to get added to the correct tab (`Media` or `Blog`).

Even though that functionality works, both the [Blog](https://testmdrs.github.io/blog/) and [Media](https://testmdrs.github.io/media/) tab lost their aesthetics compared to the style in the [original template blog](https://alembic.darn.es/blog/). Namely, 1) the banner image at the top is now gone; 2) the text formatting with the title in one line followed by the date in the "pretty" format (gray colored and in the format `29 Aug 2016`) is now in a less-attractive bullet format with date first and in the format `Aug 29, 2016`; 3) the introductory excerpt text (in the example: "A pot still is a type of still used in distilling spirits such as whisky or brandy. Heat is applied directly to the pot containing the wash (for whisky) or wine (for brandy).") is now gone.

It is unclear to me why my separation of the `_posts` folder into two separate folders seems to cause these unwanted layout side effects. Since all three of these layout issues changed at once, I am assuming they can all be solved in the same solution. Whether or not that is true, any advice on how to solve these layout issues could be very helpful. Thank you for sharing any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've removed the `posts` collection from your `_config.yml` which was setting the default `feature_image` for all posts.  Unless you add that back in or include the overrides in each individual post it will not display the header (it may or may not also affect the rest of the styles):

```
collections:
  media:
    title: Media # Needed for Siteleaf
    output: true
    description: "Recent discussions with the media." # The post list page content
    feature_text: |
      Sharing our motivations and  
      opinions with the media.
    feature_image: "https://picsum.photos/2560/600?image=866"
```

You're not actually using a media collection in either `blog/index.html` nor `media/index.html`, you're using the `post.categories` for filtering in the end, which will still causes some weird pagination once you start getting things rolling.

You may want to look at using the separate collections and then pre-building your site using paginator v2 (https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/blob/master/README-GENERATOR.md) which will allow for pagination of different collections.

**Edit 2020-01-23**

Taking a new look at your repository, you still only have one (posts) collection.  Therefore the logic for reading `feature_*` is being shared.  If you look at the include `site_feature.html` you can see how the feature_image is being parsed out of the collections.

```
{% assign collectiondata = site.collections | where: "label", page.collectionpage | first %}
```

Which in your case is why Blog and Media both have the second image `?image=213`.  Your `blog.html` and `media.html` still have the front matter `collectionpage: post`.

I still think you're going down a slippery slope which will result in things not working exactly as you want them once you get more and more posts by doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks @kendavidson. I had tried different `config.yml` file changes. My current `config.yml` now has two `posts` separately for the "Blog" and "Media" tabs, each with their own "description" and "feature_text" fields. Inside the blog/index.html and media/index.html files, I now have both set to `layout: post` and `collection page: posts`. These combinations successfully separate "media" and "blog" posts. However, for some reason, the "Media" tab has the same banner image and "feature_text" as the (and intended for) "Blog" tab. Not sure why `config.yml` does not correctly read these two posts.

Comment: Thanks @kendavidson. And I am also not sure why the `description:` fields under the `posts` of the `config.yml` file is not read either. At least, when I view the "Blog" and "Media" tab of the website, there is no description in either case. This is despite the fact that the `feature_text` and `feature_image` is read (although it is only correctly read for the "Blog" and then duplicated incorrectly for the "Media" what is intended only for the "Blog"). Sorry for the follow up here. I am trying to take into account your first main suggestion of keeping the `posts` in `config.yml`. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @kendavidson. In addition to your statement, I have seen other warnings about double blogs in Jekyll GitHub and how pagination is difficult in that case. I decided to keep one blog section and just have different category labels to visually separate the "media" and "blog". This seems more sustainable and doable within my timeframe. Thank you again for your feedback; I was able to learn several new things.